# Linkable lists of call signs in a specific zip code

Tags: united-states, software, callsign

I've been trying to build a ham related website. I'm looking for a list of call signs. Here's the trick: I need the URL to change based on the zip code. I want to be able to put the link on a page, have someone click on it and not have to do anything else. I have checked three resources: The ULS database, QRZ, and Radio QTH. The lists are there, but the URL does not change based on individual searches.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it's about web programming, not amateur radio, even though the OP wants to create a ham-related web site.

Comment: Your description is not very clear - I need the URL to change based on zip code? Are you aware you can download the entire ULS database allowing you to render it within your page?

Comment: @GlennW9IQ I suspect he wants to avoid downloading all the data to a database, implementing a process to keep the data current, and building a page to display the data.  Generating a URL with a zip code in it is a lot simpler.

Comment: @rclocher3 I argue against closing it because it's not about web programming as much as it's about finding a suitable source for ham radio license information.  The fact that the OP wants to use that data source for a web site is incidental.

Comment: How will you handle non-US ham visitors?

Comment: @mrog that's about as good as asking for a product: An information source *is* a service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use radioreference.com, as in this example:  https://www.radioreference.com/apps/ham/?action=search&zipcode=12345

Answer (score 1):

If you are building a site that allows someone to put in a zip code to see the hams around them, it may prove more beneficial to allow them to see the hams that are within a certain mile radius of the zip code. I did this for a club that was offering licensing classes and wanted to send postcards to all of the hams of a particular license class within a specified radius.

If this interests you, take a look at a site like [zipcodestogo](http://zipcodestogo.com). I programmatically entered the zip code and radius and then stripped out the zip code information from the returned page. I then used this to filter a SQL database of the ULS data that was downloaded weekly from the FCC site. The ULS download is well documented by the FCC. This is what [QRZ](http://qrz.com) uses for their U.S. call sign lookups.

You can also drive the addresses of your filtered results to place pins on Google Maps to get a nice view of the ham population in the selected area.